# compile separate .cpp files for function definitions and header files in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have two files, Book.h (header file) and Book.cpp. The header file contains my function headers for my Book class. I have placed the function bodies in my Book.cpp file.

I simply want to compile the Book.cpp file. When I attempt to, I get quite a few errors saying `overloaded function differs only by return type from '*type* Book::*functionName(void)*

I have included the header file in my Book.cpp file, as you can see below. I don't understand what is missing. I have searched online but every compiler seems to handle compiling multiple files together quite differently.

NOTE: I have also attempted to add another .cpp named menu.cpp that contains my main. In this main I have simply tried to instantiate a book object, but the compiler doesn't recognize my Book class or any of it's member functions....

Here are the contents of Book.cpp:

```
#include "Book.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    static const int CHECK_OUT_LENGTH = 21;
    Book::Book(){
        idCode = "";
        title = "";
        author = "";
    };
    Book::Book(std::string idc, std::string t, std::string a){
        idCode = idc;
        title = t;
        author = a;
    };
    int Book::getCheckOutLength(){
        return CHECK_OUT_LENGTH;
    };
    std::string Book::getIdCode(){
        return idCode;
    };
    std::string Book::getTitle(){
        return title;
    };
    std::string Book::getAuthor(){
        return author;
    };
    Locale Book::getLocation(){
        return location;
    };
    void Book::setLocation(Locale lo){
        location = lo;
    };
    Patron* Book::getCheckedOutBy(){
        return checkedOutBy; //will return the address of the current patron who has checked out the book
    };
    void Book::setCheckedOutBy(Patron* p){
         checkedOutBy = p; //will set the address of checkedOutBy pointer to the adress of the pointer p  
    };
    Patron* Book::getRequestedBy(){
        return requestedBy;
    };
    void Book::setRequestedBy(Patron* p){
        requestedBy = p;
    };
    int Book::getDateCheckedOut(){
        return dateCheckedOut;
    };
    void Book::setDateCheckedOut(int d){
        dateCheckedOut = d;
    };
```

Here are the contents of Book.h:

```
#ifndef examples_Book_h
#define examples_Book_h


class Patron;

enum Locale {ON_SHELF, ON_HOLD, CHECKED_OUT};

class Book
{
private:
    std::string idCode;
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    Locale location;
    Patron* checkedOutBy;
    Patron* requestedBy;
    int dateCheckedOut;
public:
    static const int CHECK_OUT_LENGTH = 21;
    Book();
    Book(std::string idc, std::string t, std::string a);
    int getCheckOutLength();
    std::string getIdCode();
    std::string getTitle();
    std::string getAuthor();
    Locale getLocation();
    void setLocation(Locale lo);
    Patron* getCheckedOutBy();
    void setCheckedOutBy(Patron* p);
    Patron* getRequestedBy();
    void setRequestedBy(Patron* p);
    int getDateCheckedOut();
    void setDateCheckedOut(int d);
};

#endif
```

Here are the contents of my measly little main function:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Book.h" //why won't this work?

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Book myBook;



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: book.h uses std::string so should include <string>

Comment: I can't immediately spot a problem, if you right click the include of book.h in te book.cpp file and choose to open it, does the correct file open? (i'm wondering if you havean old book.h file lurking somewhere)

Comment: please copy and paste the first few errors you get at the end of your answer

Comment: Yes, when I right click on my includes for Book.h, it opens the correct Book.h file. I also added and includes for <string> at the top of Book.h. Now I get far less errors, which is great, but compilation still fails. Now this is the only error I receive, which makes no sense since the correct Book.h file opened when I right clicked it: `c:\users\john d\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project35\project35\menu.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Book.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: to double check - does tĥe right file open if you right click the include from within menu.cpp?

Comment: Bingo. What a strange issue. I had all my header and cpp files, except for my main, in a seperate directory. I had originally used the `Add Existing file` option to (what I though was import) my other files into my project directory. I though that Visual Studio would make a copy of these files from my external directory and then place them where they needed to go in my project directory. I was wrong. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: As a side note, is there any way to set Visual Studio to copy a file and place it in my project directory when I use the `Add --> existing file` option

Comment: I don't know of an option to do that.

Comment: In the project settings you can add 'Additional include directories' which the compiler will search after it has looked in the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from the comments: in headers, ensure all types used have been declared or defined, in this case by including . And, ensure included files can be found.

Comment: Also, be sure that all your header files and all your .cpp files are in the same project directory when using Visual Studio, and know that your files will not compile without a main function, since that is the compilers "entry point".